# Sub query count in mysql

Tags: mysql, count, subquery

I have the following query which successfully gets me the data I'm after...

```
$query  = @"SELECT table1.user_id, table1.col8, table2.col5, user_tokens.expiry
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.user_id=table2.user_id
INNER JOIN user_tokens
ON user_tokens.user_id=table1.user_id 
WHERE table1.col2 = '{$userName}'";
```

I've been playing around with it to give me some extra data without a second query. The data I want is a row count from another table - table10 (that also has `user_id` as a column) where the user_id columns match.

So something like...

,

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table) as userDataCount
```

which is currently giving me a row count for the whole table, not just rows that have the same user_id as table1

I figured the inner joins I've done would only count the table10 rows where the user_id columns match the rest of the query, and the different ways I've tried of joining table10, or using an extra WHERE to say `WHERE table10.user_id = table1.user_id` are failing.

Is there a simple way to do this, or do I need two separate queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
table1.user_id, 
table1.col8, 
table2.col5, 
user_tokens.expiry, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM table
        WHERE table.user_id=table1.user_id) as uCount 
    FROM table1 
    INNER JOIN table2
    ON table1.user_id=table2.user_id
    INNER JOIN user_tokens
    ON user_tokens.user_id=table1.user_id 
    WHERE table1.col2 = '{$userName}'";
```

Comment: Thank you guys!! (SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM table
        WHERE table.user_id=table1.user_id) as uCount did the trick!!

Comment: Gidday Evan. I'm looking for a button to do that but cannot see one. How do I mark it?

Answer (score 3):

There are many possible solutions on this, one, *which I illustrated*, is joining through a subquery which separately gets the total count for every group.

```
SELECT  table1.user_id, 
        table1.col8, 
        table2.col5, 
        user_tokens.expiry,
        COALESCE(b.totalDataCount, 0) userDataCount
FROM    table1 
        INNER JOIN table2
            ON table1.user_id=table2.user_id
        INNER JOIN user_tokens
            ON user_tokens.user_id=table1.user_id 
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  user_ID, COUNT(*) totalDataCount
            FROM    table10
            GROUP   BY user_ID
        ) b ON  b.user_id = table1.user_id
WHERE   table1.col2 = '{$userName}
```